# Is a return value of 0 always a success in stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

If a stored procedure returns a value of zero, does that always mean it was run successfully? I am using MS SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Not sure what your question is. If you can write the SP and choose the return value, isn't the answer "no"?

Comment: Related info on the Return statement might help too:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578536/msdn-about-stored-procedure-default-return-value

Comment: For more detail about Store Procedure Return, you can read these article on MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188655.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, you can return something yourself

example

```
CREATE PROC pr_test AS 
SELECT 1/0

RETURN 0
GO
```

Now run it

```
DECLARE @i INT
exec @i = pr_test

SELECT @i  -- will be 0

DROP PROC pr_test
```

Now let's do it again without the return statement

```
CREATE PROC pr_test2 AS 
SELECT 1/0

GO

DECLARE @i INT
exec @i = pr_test2

SELECT @i  -- will be - 6
```

Better to use an `output parameter` to pass back statuses and or messages

Comment: How is the return value 6? and the result says - 
Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Procedure pr_test2, Line 3
Divide by zero error encountered.

(1 row(s) affected)

Answer (score 7):

An @@ERROR return value of "zero" indicates that your procedure completed without any errors.

Of course, that doesn't mean that it did what you wanted it to...

Can you be more specific about what you're looking at?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `Return` word to return any integer value from a *Stored Procedure*. That means that zero does not mean that the stored procedure was executed successfully.