# Why does the output of this simple proc change datatypes?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

In testing output values from procs, why does the final `select @TestValOut` return `0` instead of `null` or an empty string?

I understand the correct way to do this is by using `OUTPUT` parameters, so the question really becomes: ***Why is the datatype of the set value of `@TestValOut`, at execution, an integer?***

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'Custom.test') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
    DROP PROCEDURE Custom.test
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE Custom.test (
    @CurrentUserID INT = 1
    )
As
    Declare @TestValIn varchar(max)
    select @TestValIn='asdf'

GO

BEGIN TRAN

    Declare @TestValOut varchar(max)
    set @TestValOut='ffff'
    Exec @TestValOut=Custom.test @CurrentUserID=1
    select @TestValOut
ROLLBACK
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A return value in a stored procedure is always an integer, as a matter of fact you can only use an integer with a return value. The fact that you see 0 means the proc executed correctly, this is the return value that SQL Server returns telling you what the result of the proc execution is

For fun do a `select 1/0` in the proc  and you will see it won't be 0 anymore

See here

[Is a return value of 0 always a success in stored procedures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034746/is-a-return-value-of-0-always-a-success-in-stored-procedures/6034778#6034778)

here are the examples from that answer

```
CREATE PROC pr_test AS 
SELECT 1/0

RETURN 0
GO
```

Now run it

```
DECLARE @i INT
exec @i = pr_test

SELECT @i  -- will be 0

DROP PROC pr_test
```

Now let's do it again without the return statement

```
CREATE PROC pr_test2 AS 
SELECT 1/0

GO

DECLARE @i INT
exec @i = pr_test2

SELECT @i  -- will be - 6
```

Better to use an `output parameter` to pass back statuses and or messages

Comment: Nonsense, `@TestValOut` gets the return value not the result set

Comment: @ScottV: wrong. @TestValOut is assigned the value from RETURN. There is no resultset from the stored procedure

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're trying to do is use an output parameter, which should be done like this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Custom.test (
    @CurrentUserID INT = 1,
    @TestValOut varchar(max) OUTPUT
    )
As
    select @TestValOut='asdf'

GO

BEGIN TRAN    
    Declare @TestValOut varchar(max)
    Exec Custom.test @CurrentUserID=1, @TestValOut OUTPUT
    select @TestValOut
ROLLBACK
```

Comment: Yes, this is true. However the question acknowledges that this is the case -- but looks for a reasoning for the case of a(n implicit) return.

Answer (score 1):

@TestValOut is assigned the value that *would* be returned by an "RETURN" like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Custom.test (
    @CurrentUserID INT = 1
    )
As
    Declare @TestValIn varchar(max)
    select @TestValIn='asdf'

RETURN --defaults to zero, this is the value
GO
```

or

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Custom.test (
    @CurrentUserID INT = 1
    )
As
    Declare @TestValIn varchar(max)
    select @TestValIn='asdf'

RETURN 0 --this is the value
GO
```

Your stored procedure doesn't actually do anything at all: there is no resultset. To see the difference...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Custom.test (
    @CurrentUserID INT = 1
    )
As

    select * from sys.objects

    RETURN 42 --random value
GO

DECLARE @rtn int
EXEC @rtn = Custom.test
--you have the output of sys.objects now
--and the scalar RETURN value
SELECT @rtn
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicity say what value to return. Default is 0

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Custom.test (
    @CurrentUserID INT = 1
    )
As
    Declare @TestValIn varchar(max)
    select @TestValIn='asdf'

    RETURN 0

GO
```

Comment: Will give a warning: can't RETURN NULL

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Updated to return 0!